# React - combine functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I combine those two functions (handleSelectAll and handleSelectNone)? Toggle (on/off) wouldn't work here as in most cases some options would be 'checked' so you won't know whether to toggle it ALL or NONE so there need to be 2 separate buttons (at least that's what I think). What I was thinking was that the function can be shared

```
const handleSelectAll = () => {
    setCategories(oldCats => oldCats.map(category => {
        return {
          ...category,
          selected: true
        }
    }))
  }

  const handleSelectNone = () => {
    setCategories(oldCats => oldCats.map(category => {
        return {
          ...category,
          selected: false
        }
    }))
  }
```

and then the buttons in a component:

```
const Categories = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <form className="check-form">
        {props.categories.map(category => (
          <Category key={category.id} category={category} {...props} />
        ))}
      </form>
     <button onClick={props.handleSelectAll}>
          Select All
     </button>
     <button onClick={props.handleSelectNone}>
       Select None
     </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Would there be a way of just defining one function for both buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do like this, keep things simple and legible, nothing too fancy:

```js
const handleSelect = (selected = false) => {
  setCategories((oldCats) =>
    oldCats.map((category) => {
      return {
        ...category,
        selected,
      }
    })
  )
}

const handleSelectAll = () => {
  return handleSelect(true)
}

const handleSelectNone = () => {
  return handleSelect()
}
```

(the render part continues as is)

Doing like so avoids you creating that extra template function passing an argument and creating a new function on every render

Comment: Thanks. I did need to add 'false' to 'return handSelect()' otherwise there was an error about mixing controlled/uncontrolled elements

Comment: Ops, I missed that. Yeah you don't want it to be undefined

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can wrap the call for `props.handleSelectAll` and `props.handleSelectNone` with a function and pass the new value as argument:

```
const Categories = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <form className="check-form">
        {props.categories.map(category => (
          <Category key={category.id} category={category} {...props} />
        ))}
      </form>
     <button onClick={()=>props.handleSelect(true)}>
          Select All
     </button>
     <button onClick={()=>props.handleSelect(false)}>
       Select None
     </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[ `()=>props.handleSelect(true)` is an arrow function that calls `handleSelect` on click ]

And the new function will be:

```
  const handleSelect= (newValue) => {
    setCategories(oldCats => oldCats.map(category => {
        return {
          ...category,
          selected: newValue
        }
    }))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it one function using a parameter, such as

```js
const handleChangeAll = (selected) => {
    setCategories(oldCats => oldCats.map(category => {
        return {
          ...category,
          selected: selected
        }
    }))
  }
```

Then you can call this function with a parameter in each button like this:

```js
const Categories = (props) => {
  return(
    <div className="categories">
      <h2>Categories</h2>
      <form className="check-form">
        {props.categories.map(category => (
          <Category key={category.id} category={category} {...props} />
        ))}
      </form>
     <button onClick={() => props.handleChangeAll(true)}>
          Select All
     </button>
     <button onClick={() => props.handleChangeAll(false)}>
       Select None
     </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm not downvoting this, but I'd personally avoid declaring a fn like this on every render pass. Also, I'd rename `value` to `selected` on that fn signature.

Comment: @enapupe that's how I've always done things like that for the onClick part, is there a better way of doing this that I can use?

Comment: It's a bit personal. I have this `Button` component that receives `onClick` and `onClickWith`, so I can send an argument there without declaring a fn on render. Another option is do like I did on my answer to this question.

Answer (score -3):

`selected: !category.selected`

```
const handleSelectNone = () => {
    setCategories(oldCats => oldCats.map(category => {
        return {
          ...category,
          selected: !category.selected
        }
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Because that would generate a set of mixed toggles, not uniformly select/unselect all

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.